# AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'lineplot' - already updated to 0.9.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I need help with getting lineplot running. I've already updated conda and Seaborn using pip and conda.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this? I am using Jupyter w/ Python 3.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5086873db64c> in <module>()
----> 1 rawx = sns.relplot(x="Timestamp",y="X0",kind="line",data=raw)

AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'relplot'
```

Comment: Post text as text, not images; provide the actual code that's causing the problem; provide the traceback... unless we have these things, there is no way for us to help you. Please review [minimal, complete, and verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and, more generally, [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The picture is simply proof showing that the packages are installed. Don't see it necessary to show that text as it just makes a wall of text.

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, but if you're unable to fix this yourself, you might not want to make too many assumptions about what would or would not be useful for other people to help you solve it. The guidelines are there for a reason, and if you decide to ignore them, you limit our ability to help you.

Comment: Do you actually have any suggestions on how to try and find a solution or are you just trying to work on formatting? Based on my excessive googling of this problem, I've already provided all the details that previous similar questions have asked. What specific information do you need to troubleshoot this because I can't figure out what you need. You already saw the content of the image, but you haven't given any suggestions on how to actually tackle the problem.

Comment: You've provided a traceback from the command line, which contains only one line of code (context is important), and doesn't come close to a verifiable example (which I suggested in my first comment). The error is clear enough, but since you've provided no way to reproduce this or information about your environment, why it's actually happening is anyone's guess. I can't give you suggestions on how to tackle the problem if you don't provide enough information to _identify_ the problem.

Comment: I guess check that you are installing seaborn 0.9 in the correct place. In addition, try doing `print (seaborn.__version__)` at the top of your script to double check your version number

Comment: Also, report back what `print(seaborn.__file__)` gives.

Comment: ..or since no feedback is provided, I'll vote to close as well.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, based on what you have given, can only think of checking version of seaborn with:

```
pip freeze | grep seaborn
pip3 freeze | grep seaborn
```

And try this within the conda environment:

```
pip3 install seaborn==0.9.0
```

Or:

```
conda install seaborn==0.9.0
```

and to make sure you are actually loading the proper version of Python that has the updated seaborn.